# Allign jQuery button in new line

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have simply 3 buttons in jQuery dialog form. I want to align first button at the center top and other two together at the second line/row. How i can manipulate the buttons?

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#wrapper').dialog({

            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Create new user',
            buttons: {
                "Register": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("register");


                },
                "Send": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("send");


                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                }
            }
        });

        $("a").click(function (e) {
        $('#wrapper').dialog('open');
        $("#wrapper").css("background", "#E18728");
        $("#wrapper").dialog({ width: 'auto', height: 'auto' });

        return false;

        });

    });

</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Provide the html also.

Comment: Actually i used html to create a table form and bind into dialog. Dialog buttons and html forms are 2 different elements in this case. i don`t control buttons from html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :- wrap Register button inside `<center></center>` (this tag deprecated in HTML4, so may not work in HTML5. You can use `<div align="center"></div>` instead to wrap button) when dialog open.

Use below jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#wrapper').dialog({

            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Create new user',
            open: function(event) {
                 // wrap button inside center tag
                 $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button:contains("Register")').wrap('<center></center>');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Register": function () {
                    $(this).dialog( "register");


                },
                "Send": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("send");


                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                }
            }
        });

        $("a").click(function (e) {
        $('#wrapper').dialog('open');
        $("#wrapper").css("background", "#E18728");
        $("#wrapper").dialog({ width: 'auto', height: 'auto' });

        return false;

        });

    });
```

**[Demo JSFiddle with Center tag](http://jsfiddle.net/bWsTg/37/)**

In case of HTML5, use below

```
open: function(event) {
     $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button:contains("Register")').wrap('<div align="center"></div>');
 }
```

**[Demo JSFiddle for HTML5](http://jsfiddle.net/bWsTg/39/)**

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer. How about how i can arrange button looks good instead they congested middle. something like top button width %100 and bottoms %50, %50.

Comment: You can define css classess and use .addClass() for 100%, 50% after .wrap() method call

Comment: Is there a way for newer jQuery versions now that we are in 2019?

Comment: You can check https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/ and https://jquery.com/download/ for new jquery version